# Detecting lost focus for NSTableView in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

Is there any way to detect and respond when a control on a window loses focus?

I want to run some code when a user leaves NSTableView.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in 10.6 and later by using [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i) to observe the window's `firstResponder`. It will change when the focused control in the window changes.

Put the code you want to run in the observing object's [`observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-BBCBDGCJ) method.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I've needed.

Comment: Any example how to do that? Thanks.